# IBM SPSS - Split scatter graphs

Tags: spss

On IBM SPSS I am trying to create four simple scatter graphs for the following data.
I want to plot weight on one axis, carbohydrates on another axis, but I want a graph for four different seasons. 
I have tried making a simple scatter, by putting weight on x axis and carbs on the y axis but am unsure how to create the four different seasons.
I tried putting seasons in the panel - column, but I just get four graphs on one single line.
Can anyone help with this?

Comment: please provide data samples and more input so the community can help you

Answer (score 0):

In the menus, select Data>Split File, click on the Compare groups option on the right, move the season variable into the Groups Based on box, then click OK. Then just run the simple scatterplot and you'll get one for each season. Make sure to go back and select the "Analyze all cases, do not create groups" option in the Data>Split File dialog box before you do further analyses where you want to include all cases. The split status is displayed in the lower right corner of the Data Editor window. Reopening the file will automatically turn off the splitting.